# Передвинуть элемент на место клика

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как передвинуть элемент на место клика, чтобы он стал ровно по центру?

```css
.go {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="go"></div>
```

Comment: Так как надо-то - на место клика или ровно по центру?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', fn, false);
function fn(event) {
  var el = document.querySelector('.go')
  el.style.transform = 'translate(' + (event.pageX - el.offsetWidth / 2) + 'px ,' + (event.pageY - el.offsetHeight / 2) + 'px)'
}
```

```css
.go {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="go"></div>
```